# Java How to convert a GenericRecord to a json string?

Tags: java, json, avro

I am trying to convert a GenericRecord to a json string so I can pass it to something like a JSONObject. I am thinking about using the JsonEncoder to do this. Right now I have something like:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JsonEncoder jsonEncoder = new JsonEncoder(genericRecord.getSchema(),out);
```

However it's giving me an error:

```
error: incompatible types: ByteArrayOutputStream cannot be converted to JsonGenerator
```

Per the source code of JsonEncoder it should have a construct that takes in a outputstream so I am not sure why I am getting this error.
Can someone suggest how to fix the problem? Any other suggestion on how to convert a GenericRecord to a json string is also welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's [this `JsonEncoder`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.4/api/java/org/apache/avro/io/JsonEncoder.html) it doesn't have any public constructors. It says to "Construct using `EncoderFactory`." An [`EncoderFactory`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.4/api/java/org/apache/avro/io/EncoderFactory.html) does have a [`jsonEncoder`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.4/api/java/org/apache/avro/io/EncoderFactory.html#jsonEncoder(org.apache.avro.Schema,%20java.io.OutputStream)) factory method that takes a `Schema` and an `OutputStream`, though.

I just tried it out, and the way to create a `JsonEncoder` is:

```
JsonEncoder jsonEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(genericRecord.getSchema(), out);
```